# Marshalling fixed arrays (of type WCHAR, BOOL)

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a following method from IDL file used by COM object:

```
HRESULT GetData([out] WCHAR model[40], [out] BOOL isSupported[3]);
```

I wanted to call this method from C++ .NET code so I've created an interface in order to cast created COM server to this form, this is a method from the interface defined in C#:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
void GetData(
     [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out char[] model,
     [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 3)] out bool[] isSupported
);
```

Next I'm trying to run method in C++ CLI from the interface (COM object was casted to the interface declared in C#)

```
 cli::array<char,1>^ temp1 = gcnew cli::array<char,1>(40);
 cli::array<bool,1>^ temp2 = gcnew cli::array<bool,1>(3);

 COMInterface->GetData(temp1, temp2);
```

I get the error during complication:

> Error    139 error C2664: 'COMInterface::GetData' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'cli::array ^' to
>   'cli::array ^%'

I've tried many solution to marshall WCHAR[40] (using LPArray, LPWSTR and so on) everytime without success (complication errors or exception during casting COM object to invalid interface)

What am I missing? How should I marshall fixed array? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The use of the `out` keyword is wrong here. You'll have to remove it. But I'm not convinced that `UnmanagedType.LPArray` will match the unmanaged code, and I'm sure that `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` will not.

Comment: The IDL is already *very* strange, you just don't declare strings and arrays like that.  Not so sure how much luck you'll have, don't tinker with the pinvoke declaration.  You keep the compiler happy by *not* initializing the arrays, they are created by the marshaller.  Call with GetData(%temp1, %temp2).  Keep your fingers crossed to improve your odds.